# How do I delete unwanted Apple ID's?

Tags: apple-id

I'm going thru a phone swap, and I now realize that I have multiple ID's

- "codename"
- "codename@example.com"
- "realname@example.com"

I've tested all three, and they all have different login passwords. Not sure how I got here but I'd like to clean the mess up.  Is there any way to delete / remove / erase unwanted ID's so they don't exist anymore?  (Note: their existence creates total havoc with any type of ID edit...)

I see from [Frequently asked questions about Apple ID](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5622) that I can't merge the apple ID's, but can I simply delete the unwanted ID's?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no easy way to disable / delete the Apple ID from Apple's servers, but you can delete all the personal data (contacts, calendars, mail) and then change the contact information and security questions / password to ones that you will no longer use or ever enter into a device. I would write them down and file it in a safe *just in case* you change your mind down the road. If you want to re-use that email with Apple in the future, you may want to change the Apple ID to a disposable email and clear all other emails from that account if you ever want to use those "real" email addresses with your actual AppleID.

- [How do I remove or delete an @me.com email?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49228/how-do-i-remove-or-delete-an-me-com-email)
- [Remove an email address from apple-ID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62468/remove-an-email-address-from-apple-id)
- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5622

In short - you can and should delete the obsolete ID from all your devices. In the past, there's not been a way to delete an account without Apple support speaking with a service engineer to delete an account on the server side.

Comment: Up vote for this clear answer. ie Disposable email :)

Comment: I don't really like this answer (from our friends at Apple) but I begrudgingly accept it.  One has to ask, how did this happen?  Why does iCloud require an apple ID with an email in it in the first place? Wish there was a document somewhere that described "Apple ID Use - Mystery Logic and Mediocre Design".  I'm obviously not a fan.  Oh, wait, is this a new NSA requirement?

Comment: @zipzit Think of malicious destruction/impersonation. If Apple were to delete your account forever, what recourse would you have if someone else requested the deletion? Basically, the penalty for one event in a thousand might be causing Apple to make policy that they don't delete accounts since actually handling it is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can , you have to call apple support and tell them why, you also have to be sure your find my devices is off. Apple has to do it for you.