# Can I delete a me.com email account

Tags: icloud, email

I've looked at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49228/how-do-i-remove-or-delete-an-me-com-email) -- it has the same title as mine, but it is quite old.

I had a mac.com and a me.com account through MobileMe back in the stone age. I've always found the me.com address annoying and would like to remove it.

I have made it inactive by using mail.app > accounts.

I know I can delete an email alias. The me.com account is not shown on icloud.com as an alias. It shows as a discrete email address.

Is there any way to remove it completely?

Thanks

Update:

Here's a screenshot of my iCloud email settings.

[image]

Comment: The linked question/answer is still true - you cannot merge or delete an Apple ID. You can change the primary address, but not the ID itself.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the me.com email is itself an AppleId? Or is it part of my main AppleId? Thanks the linked question is a bit different -- he was looking to delete an AppleId.

Comment: It can be... it doesn't have to be. I have a me.com to which apple 'kindly' added an iCloud.com that I never wanted or asked for. The Apple ID is still the me.com - i.e. that's what I sign in with, the other is just an unused 'alias' I guess. [To add more complexity, I also have another company.com ID that was from long before me.com started. I had a mac.com account, back in the victorian era, 90s, but never kept track of it & I guess it vanished rather than migrated.. no idea what happened to it..

Comment: This - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245864/changing-appleid-email-address?rq=1 - & links from comments may be pertinent

Comment: I should have been clearer - my AppleId is my mac.com account. I have no use for the me.com, and I can live with the iCloud.com acct (I use it for very special purposes, like holding junk)

Comment: I'm still not sure whether you mean they are 3 separate IDs, or whether they are in effect just aliases of each other, new addresses you were given as the old ones 'expired'. Though, tbh, whichever way, you can't delete them, simply sign out & ignore.

Comment: There is one account:  mac.com. That's my AppleID. The me.com account should be an alias, but it does not list in the aliases section, and I cant seem to do anything.. I'll update my question with a screen shot.

Comment: You can't get rid of it. It's just there. You're of course not forced to use it, but you also can't disable it. It's an alias in the sense that emails sent to me.com will go to icloud.com but it isn't an alias configurable (or removable) by the user.